# Avoiding nullable foreign keys in many-to-many table

Tags: sql, database, orm, h2, ormlite

I have a many-to-many table that looks somewhat like this.
It's accessed through ormlite and stored in an embedded h2 database.

```
@DatabaseField(id = true)
private String id;

@DatabaseField(foreign = true, canBeNull = false, uniqueCombo = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
private ForeignOne foreignOne;

@DatabaseField(foreign = true, canBeNull = false, uniqueCombo = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
private ForeignTwo foreignTwo;
```

If I try to store an instance in which one or both of the foreign members are *null* the DAO object throws an exception as expected as the annotation states *canBeNull = false*.

However if one or both of the foreign members are set to instances that do **not** exist in the database I am able to perform the insertion into the database and the next time I retrieve the instance from the database those foreign members that did not exist on insertion are *null*.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `not null` constraint merely means the field cannot be null, it does not mean it has to be a valid key. If you want to ensure that your foreign key actually points to a row in the foreign table, you need to create a [**foreign key constraint**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp), which is not fully supported in ORMLite. Instead you have to use a [custom column definition](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#columnDefinition%28%29), something like

```
@DatabaseField(foreign = true,
               columnDefinition = "integer references foreignOne(id)" )
private ForeignOne foreignOne;
```

to get ORMLite to create one. Or you can create the h2 database yourself and include one.